# Is it possible to link to an outside url from within an xml document?

Tags: xml, hyperlink

I am using a flash web template that pulls the images from an xml document. I want to link from an image after it is clicked on to another portion of the site.

Here is some sample code from the document:

```
<gallery id="1" name="public relations">
    <image width="121" height="161" image="images/pr/pr_01.jpg"/>
```

I want the image "pr_01.jpg to link to a url.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a hyperlink tag in xml is:

```
<test><xhtml:a href="link here">Test Link</xhtml:a></test>
```

As far as getting the link when the image is clicked, haven't done that before.  I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: Thanks, but that breaks the link to all the images somehow.

Comment: I see where you were going with this now.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate it! This is way beyond my knowledge and I have searched everywhere (that I know of)